# Nonsingular matrix must have a solution proof

Tags: linear-algebra

Im reading the book linear algebra from http://joshua.smcvt.edu/linearalgebra/.
In the book it says that a system has no solution if there is no particular solution and that a system has 1 solution if there is a particular solution and the homogenous solution is unique and that a system has many solution if there is a particular solution and there are many homogenous solution.

Then later on they say a nonsingular will always have a solution because it has a unique homogenous solution... but then what about the particular solution... what if the system has a unique homogenous solution but no particular solution?

Comment: I'm reading the same book now, and he didn't prove this point using what he established before it.

Comment: By the definition on the prior page, a square matrix is nonsingular if it is the matrix of coefficients of a homogeneous system with a unique solution.  So there is a sequence of Gauss's method steps that brings the matrix of coefficients to echelon form.  Take the given system and apply those steps.  Now back substitution produces the unique solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to solve a linear system $A(x)=b$, where $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix. The fact that $A$ is non singular means that $A$ is invertible, thus $A^{-1}(b)$ is a solution of the equation.

When $A$ is not invertible, you need first to determine the space of homogeneous solutions which are the solution of $A(x)=0$. Denote by $Ker(A)$ this space of homogeneous solutions, and let $x_0$ be a particular solution, $A(x_0)=b$, the solutions are $x_0+a,a\in ker(A)$.

Comment: But what if there is no particular solution?

Comment: There is always a particular solution if $A$ is invertible, if you solve $A(x)=b$, the particular solution is $A^{-1}(b)$.

Comment: @TsemoAristide the author first uses this definition after discussing the general solution idea :

`A square matrix is nonsingular if it is the matrix of coefficients
of a homogeneous system with a unique solution. It is singular otherwise, that
is, if it is the matrix of coefficients of a homogeneous system with infinitely many solutions.`

He didn't talk about invertibility yet, so can this statement be proved without using ideas related to the inverse of the matrix?